# Bootstrap cards overlapping

Tags: html, css, card

Im looking at aligning bootstrap cards and make them responsive. I have them centred but they are overlapping and not sure where I'm going wrong. its like its all sticking to the left. This is for email development where the width has a max of 680px.

Any help will be much appreciated!

```css
/** {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  
  body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  }
*/
  .email-background{
    background-color: lightgrey;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    padding: 20px 5px 50px 5px;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .email-container{
    background-color: #ffff;
    max-width: 680px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    padding-top: 25px;
  }
/*
  .features .smaller-text{
    font-size: smaller;
    display: inline-block;
  }
*/
  .price{
    color: turquoise;
  }
/*
  .icon-case{
    height: 1em;
    width: 1em;
    float: left;
  }
*/
  .view-btn{
    background-color: #0fbd9a;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 15px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 15px;
    float: right;
  }
 

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

/* Float four columns side by side */
.email-column {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

/* Remove extra left and right margins, due to padding */
.email-row {
  margin: 0 -5px;
  padding-top: 25px;

}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.email-row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

/* Responsive columns */
@media screen and (max-width: 680px) {
  .email-column {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
}

/* Style the counter cards */
.card {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding: 26px;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>SkyScanner Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="email-background">
        <div class="email-container">
            <p class="car-titles"><strong>Check out these sweet rides</strong></p>
            <div class="email-row">
                <div class="email-column">
                    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                        <img src="/assets/economy.png" class="card-img-top" alt="Car Pic">
                        <div class="card-body">
                          <h5 class="card-title">Car 1</h5>
                          <h6>2-3 Doors</h6>
                          <div class="features">
                            <h6 class="smaller-text"><small><img class="icon-case" src="/assets/original.png">4 Seats</small></h6>
                            <h6 class="smaller-text"><small><img class="icon-case" src="/assets/suitcase.png">2</small></h6>
                            </div>
                            <div class="pricing-text">
                                <h6 class="smaller-text"><small>from</small></h6>
                                <h6><strong class="price">£33</strong><small> per day</small></h6>
                            </div>
                          <a class="view-btn" href="#">View <img src="/assets/arrow.png"></a>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                </div>
                <div class="email-column">
                    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                        <img src="/assets/economy.png" class="card-img-top" alt="Car Pic">
                        <div class="card-body">
                          <h5 class="card-title">Car 2</h5>
                          <h6>2-3 Doors</h6>
                          <div class="features">
                            <h6 class="smaller-text"><small><img class="icon-case" src="/assets/original.png">4 Seats</small></h6>
                            <h6 class="smaller-text"><small><img class="icon-case" src="/assets/suitcase.png">2</small></h6>
                            </div>
                            <div class="pricing-text">
                                <h6 class="smaller-text"><small>from</small></h6>
                                <h6><strong class="price">£33</strong><small> per day</small></h6>
                            </div>
                          <a class="view-btn" href="#">View <img src="/assets/arrow.png"></a>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="email-row">
                <div class="email-column">
                    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                        <img src="/assets/economy.png" class="card-img-top" alt="Car Pic">
                        <div class="card-body">
                          <h5 class="card-title">Car 3</h5>
                          <h6>2-3 Doors</h6>
                            <div class="features">
                            <h6 class="smaller-text"><small><img class="icon-case" src="/assets/original.png">4 Seats</small></h6>
                            <h6 class="smaller-text"><small><img class="icon-case" src="/assets/suitcase.png">2</small></h6>
                            </div>
                            <div class="pricing-text">
                                <h6 class="smaller-text"><small>from</small></h6>
                                <h6><strong class="price">£33</strong><small> per day</small></h6>
                            </div>
                          <a class="view-btn" href="#">View<img src="/assets/arrow.png"></a>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                </div>
                <div class="email-column">
                    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                        <img src="/assets/economy.png" class="card-img-top" alt="Car Pic">
                        <div class="card-body">
                          <h5 class="card-title">Car 4</h5>
                          <h6>2-3 Doors</h6>
                          <div class="features">
                          <h6 class="smaller-text"><small><img class="icon-case" src="/assets/original.png">4 Seats</small></h6>
                          <h6 class="smaller-text"><small><img class="icon-case" src="/assets/suitcase.png">2</small></h6>
                          </div>
                          <div class="pricing-text">
                          <h6 class="smaller-text"><small>from</small></h6>
                          <h6><strong class="price">£33</strong><small> per day</small></h6>
                          </div>
                          <a class="view-btn" href="#">View<img src="/assets/arrow.png"></a>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                </div>

            </div>


        </div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you want as output? Two per row?

Comment: yes that's correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a fixed column width of 25% but then you're telling the cards to be 18rem (inline). Remove the column width and just set the cards to the size you want in your actual card class rather than inline.

I didn't want to re-write your entire project, but I'd suggest looking into Bootstraps flex containers over using floats (hence the sticking to the left) so you can get everything to line up better and have more control and not have to worry about elements shifting when the screen size changes

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/flex/

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.email-background {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 20px 5px 50px 5px;
  width: 100%;
}

.email-container {
  background-color: #ffff;
  max-width: 680px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding-top: 25px;
}


/*
  .features .smaller-text{
    font-size: smaller;
    display: inline-block;
  }
*/

.price {
  color: turquoise;
}


/*
  .icon-case{
    height: 1em;
    width: 1em;
    float: left;
  }
*/

.view-btn {
  background-color: #0fbd9a;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 15px;
  float: right;
}


/* Float four columns side by side */

.email-column {
  float: left;
  padding: 0 10px;
}


/* Remove extra left and right margins, due to padding */

.email-row {
  margin: 0 -5px;
  padding-top: 25px;
}


/* Clear floats after the columns */

.email-row::after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}


/* Responsive columns */

@media screen and (max-width: 680px) {
  .email-column {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
}


/* Style the counter cards */

.card {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding: 26px;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 18rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>SkyScanner Test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="email-background">
    <div class="email-container">
      <p class="car-titles"><strong>Check out these sweet rides</strong></p>
      <div class="email-row">
        <div class="email-column">
          <div class="card">
            <img src="/assets/economy.png" class="card-img-top" alt="Car Pic">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Car 1</h5>
              <h6>2-3 Doors</h6>
              <div class="features">
                <h6 class="smaller-text"><small><img class="icon-case" src="/assets/original.png">4 Seats</small></h6>
                <h6 class="smaller-text"><small><img class="icon-case" src="/assets/suitcase.png">2</small></h6>
              </div>
              <div class="pricing-text">
                <h6 class="smaller-text"><small>from</small></h6>
                <h6><strong class="price">£33</strong><small> per day</small></h6>
              </div>
              <a class="view-btn" href="#">View <img src="/assets/arrow.png"></a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="email-column">
          <div class="card">
            <img src="/assets/economy.png" class="card-img-top" alt="Car Pic">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Car 2</h5>
              <h6>2-3 Doors</h6>
              <div class="features">
                <h6 class="smaller-text"><small><img class="icon-case" src="/assets/original.png">4 Seats</small></h6>
                <h6 class="smaller-text"><small><img class="icon-case" src="/assets/suitcase.png">2</small></h6>
              </div>
              <div class="pricing-text">
                <h6 class="smaller-text"><small>from</small></h6>
                <h6><strong class="price">£33</strong><small> per day</small></h6>
              </div>
              <a class="view-btn" href="#">View <img src="/assets/arrow.png"></a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="email-row">
        <div class="email-column">
          <div class="card">
            <img src="/assets/economy.png" class="card-img-top" alt="Car Pic">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Car 3</h5>
              <h6>2-3 Doors</h6>
              <div class="features">
                <h6 class="smaller-text"><small><img class="icon-case" src="/assets/original.png">4 Seats</small></h6>
                <h6 class="smaller-text"><small><img class="icon-case" src="/assets/suitcase.png">2</small></h6>
              </div>
              <div class="pricing-text">
                <h6 class="smaller-text"><small>from</small></h6>
                <h6><strong class="price">£33</strong><small> per day</small></h6>
              </div>
              <a class="view-btn" href="#">View<img src="/assets/arrow.png"></a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="email-column">
          <div class="card">
            <img src="/assets/economy.png" class="card-img-top" alt="Car Pic">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Car 4</h5>
              <h6>2-3 Doors</h6>
              <div class="features">
                <h6 class="smaller-text"><small><img class="icon-case" src="/assets/original.png">4 Seats</small></h6>
                <h6 class="smaller-text"><small><img class="icon-case" src="/assets/suitcase.png">2</small></h6>
              </div>
              <div class="pricing-text">
                <h6 class="smaller-text"><small>from</small></h6>
                <h6><strong class="price">£33</strong><small> per day</small></h6>
              </div>
              <a class="view-btn" href="#">View<img src="/assets/arrow.png"></a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>


    </div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: That worked a treat thank you! yeah ill take a look might be a bit easier.

Comment: I cannot suggest it enough, especially since bootstrap has classes for it and can be very specific so you don’t have to write it all yourself. Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 0):

It's that `float:left` you have on `.email-column` who is causing the overlapping. I removed it an change `.email-column` to an `inline-block`, and it gives the below output.

> You can have a cleaner solution with Flexbox or CSS Grid, but I'm not sure if that would work in emails readers.

```css
/** {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  
  body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  }
*/
  .email-background{
    background-color: lightgrey;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    padding: 20px 5px 50px 5px;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .email-container{
    background-color: #ffff;
    max-width: 680px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    padding-top: 25px;
  }
/*
  .features .smaller-text{
    font-size: smaller;
    display: inline-block;
  }
*/
  .price{
    color: turquoise;
  }
/*
  .icon-case{
    height: 1em;
    width: 1em;
    float: left;
  }
*/
  .view-btn{
    background-color: #0fbd9a;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 15px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 15px;
    float: right;
  }
 

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

/* Float four columns side by side */
.email-column {
  display:inline-block;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

/* Remove extra left and right margins, due to padding */
.email-row {
  margin: 0 -5px;
  padding-top: 25px;

}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.email-row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

/* Responsive columns */
@media screen and (max-width: 680px) {
  .email-column {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
}

/* Style the counter cards */
.card {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding: 26px;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="email-background">
  <div class="email-container">
    <p class="car-titles"><strong>Check out these sweet rides</strong></p>
    <div class="email-row">
      <div class="email-column">
        <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
          <img src="/assets/economy.png" class="card-img-top" alt="Car Pic">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Car 1</h5>
            <h6>2-3 Doors</h6>
            <div class="features">
              <h6 class="smaller-text"><small><img class="icon-case" src="/assets/original.png">4 Seats</small></h6>
              <h6 class="smaller-text"><small><img class="icon-case" src="/assets/suitcase.png">2</small></h6>
            </div>
            <div class="pricing-text">
              <h6 class="smaller-text"><small>from</small></h6>
              <h6><strong class="price">£33</strong><small> per day</small></h6>
            </div>
            <a class="view-btn" href="#">View <img src="/assets/arrow.png"></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="email-column">
        <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
          <img src="/assets/economy.png" class="card-img-top" alt="Car Pic">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Car 2</h5>
            <h6>2-3 Doors</h6>
            <div class="features">
              <h6 class="smaller-text"><small><img class="icon-case" src="/assets/original.png">4 Seats</small></h6>
              <h6 class="smaller-text"><small><img class="icon-case" src="/assets/suitcase.png">2</small></h6>
            </div>
            <div class="pricing-text">
              <h6 class="smaller-text"><small>from</small></h6>
              <h6><strong class="price">£33</strong><small> per day</small></h6>
            </div>
            <a class="view-btn" href="#">View <img src="/assets/arrow.png"></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="email-row">
      <div class="email-column">
        <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
          <img src="/assets/economy.png" class="card-img-top" alt="Car Pic">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Car 3</h5>
            <h6>2-3 Doors</h6>
            <div class="features">
              <h6 class="smaller-text"><small><img class="icon-case" src="/assets/original.png">4 Seats</small></h6>
              <h6 class="smaller-text"><small><img class="icon-case" src="/assets/suitcase.png">2</small></h6>
            </div>
            <div class="pricing-text">
              <h6 class="smaller-text"><small>from</small></h6>
              <h6><strong class="price">£33</strong><small> per day</small></h6>
            </div>
            <a class="view-btn" href="#">View<img src="/assets/arrow.png"></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="email-column">
        <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
          <img src="/assets/economy.png" class="card-img-top" alt="Car Pic">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Car 4</h5>
            <h6>2-3 Doors</h6>
            <div class="features">
              <h6 class="smaller-text"><small><img class="icon-case" src="/assets/original.png">4 Seats</small></h6>
              <h6 class="smaller-text"><small><img class="icon-case" src="/assets/suitcase.png">2</small></h6>
            </div>
            <div class="pricing-text">
              <h6 class="smaller-text"><small>from</small></h6>
              <h6><strong class="price">£33</strong><small> per day</small></h6>
            </div>
            <a class="view-btn" href="#">View<img src="/assets/arrow.png"></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```